# Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL. (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I've cloned a flask chat app respo on Git (link: https://github.com/techwithtim/Chat-Web-App). But when I logged in and try to send a message from the form, the server said that `The method is not allowed for the requested URL.`

I'm not sure because the Database file is separated, however I think the issues is in the

```
@view.route("/")
@view.route("/home")
def home():
    """
    displays home page if logged in
    :return: None
    """
    if NAME_KEY not in session:
        return redirect(url_for("views.login"))

    return render_template("index.html", **{"session": session})

@view.route("/get_messages")
def get_messages():
    """
    :return: all messages stored in database
    """
    db = DataBase()
    msgs = db.get_all_messages(MSG_LIMIT)
    messages = remove_seconds_from_messages(msgs)

    return jsonify(messages)
```

and the send message is `index.html` like

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="messages" class="overflow-auto msgs" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:500px;">
    </div>
    <form method="POST" id="msgForm" action="" style="bottom:0; margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" aria-label="Message" id="msg">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="sendBtn">Send</button>
              </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the view.route nomenclature. Can you try app.route instead? You might also have to include the valid methods for that route, as in:  @app.route('/rule_define', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

Comment: @Ben view is app configure as default, I just cloned the respo from Git. adding methods=['GET', 'POST'] also not worked.